# Grabbing some part of string using SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below result:

```
Column-1           Column-2
1                    500 - xyz123   
2                    600 - xyz456
```

I want the result like:

```
Column-1           Column-2
1                    500 - ZZ xyz123   
2                    600 - ZZ xyz456
```

I just want to add `ZZ` in the `Column-2`.

Can anybody suggest something for a fresher to work around? Please.

Comment: Take a look at the STUFF function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring additional information it's impossible to know if the following is adequate, but it works for your sample data:

```
SELECT REPLACE([Column-2],'- x','- ZZ x')
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks alot i did tried REPLACE but was missing some part of it.. This is perfect.

Comment: You might consider using STUFF instead of this replace. That way you can add ZZ regardless of the actual contents.

Answer (score 0):

Using STUFF:

```
SELECT STUFF([Column-2],CHARINDEX('-',[Column-2]) + 1,1,' ZZ ') FROM [table_name]
```